# Bound on $|x \cdot y|$ from below

Tags: inner-products, upper-lower-bounds

Take $x$ and $y$ to be real $n$-dimensional vectors with an angle $\theta$ between them. Also take "$\cdot$" to mean the real dot product. We can bound $|x \cdot y|$ from above pretty easily by doing:
\begin{align}
|x\cdot y| &= |x||y||\cos \theta| \\
&\leq |x||y|
\end{align}
since $|\cos \theta | \leq 1$. You can bound $|x \cdot y|$ from below by $0$ since $|\cos \theta| \geq 0$. It would appear $0$ is as good as it gets using this method but does anyone have an expression which bounds $|x \cdot y|$ from below using $|x|$ and $|y|$?

Comment: The best you have is $0\leq |x\cdot y|$ and this is just because the absolute value. Take any pair of non-zero orthogonal vectors to see that this lower bound is achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no - if you take any orthogonal basis vectors $b_1$ and $b_2$, then $b_1 \cdot b_2 = 0$, so if $x$ and $y$ are scalar multiples of $b_1$ and $b_2$ respectively then $|x \cdot y| = |x||y||b_1 \cdot b_2| = 0$.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense yet.
"from below using |x| and |y| ?"  Your answer uses |x| and |y|, yet I read "No", meaning no it does not use |x| and |y|.  Perhaps, OP originally meant **only** |x| and |y|?

Comment: My answer explains that it doesn't matter what $|x|$ and $|y|$ are, if you don't know the angle between them then the lower bound on their dot product is always zero.

Comment: Then perhaps, "It doesn't matter what |x| and |y| are..."
Because as stated the question is "... does anyone have an expression which bounds |x⋅y|  from below using |x|  and |y| ? " and your answer means or implies "No, [I don't bound $|x \cdot y|$ by |x| and |y|

Comment: @ConMan Thanks for the answer, I guessed as much and technically speaking $0$ still does bound $| x \cdot y|$ from below in terms of $|x|$ and $|y|$, just not in a very useful way.